# Repeated RSA en/decryption fails sometimes with Plaintext Too Large error

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, private-key, public-key

Background:

I'm trying to apply a series of RSA encryption and decryption steps on a short plaintext (e. g. 32 bytes).  Each step has a dedicated RSA key of, e. g. 2048 bytes.  I'm using the Crypto Python package for this.

The first question I have is this:

```
 keyAlice = RSA.generate(2048)
 print keyAlice.size()
```

This prints `2047` instead of `2048`.  The number I have to give must be a multiple of 256, so trying to use `2049` as input instead failed.

Can anybody tell me why the `size()` method returns a different size than I entered?

This strangeness would not bother me, but it might be a clue as to what is going on concerning my main problem:

For my goal the sender (Alice) shall apply several steps, e. g.

1. apply Bob's public key (encrypt)
2. apply Alice's private key (decrypt)

(I assume that all keys are of the same size.)

The receiver (Bob) can then apply the inverse:

1. apply Alice's public key (encrypt)
2. apply Bob's private key (decrypt)

The result of any en/decryption step produces a `str` of 256 bytes (2048 bits).

> Note: Sometimes the result is shorter, e. g. 255 bytes; as I found out this means stripped zero-bytes at the beginning; padding them solves the issue.

If I use this as input for the next step, this works

- always, in case only encryption is used
- always, in case only decryption is used
- In case encryption and decryption are combined, this works most of the time; 
   but sometimes it fails, raising a `ValueError: Plaintext too large`.

I tried to figure out in which cases this `ValueError` occurs, which *kind* of input makes it happen, but it happens so rarely (~3% of the cases) that I found no simple explanation (and thus no workaround).

My questions are:

1. Why does the `size()` method return `2047` for a 2048-bit key?  (See above.)
2. Why do the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods *sometimes* have problems with an input of 2048 bit (while they mostly have no trouble handling it)?
3. Why do they *never* have any trouble if the input is the result of a former call of the same type (e. g. `encrypt(encrypt(x))` never fails)?
4. In case my approach to cascade these calls is bound to fails due to logical reasons I just don't see yet, how can I make a cascade of applying public and private keys without bloating the input in each step massively (e. g. by chunking)?

Here's some code I'm using which demonstrates the problem:

```
import Crypto.Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

s = 0.
for i in range(1000):
  keyAlice = RSA.generate(2048)
  keyBob = RSA.generate(2048)
  x = Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes(32)
  j = 0
  try:
    while True:
      x, = keyAlice.encrypt(x, 0)
      j += 1
      x = keyBob.decrypt(x)
      j += 1
  except ValueError:
    s += j
    print j, s / (i+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA is an algebraic cryptosystem. It works on numbers and not on bytes. The encryption is given through `Enc(m,e,n) := me mod n = c` where `m` is the message, `e` is the public exponent, `n` is the modulus and `c` is the ciphertext. It is important to note that `m < n` must be strictly true. Otherwise, it would not be decryptable.
For completeness sake the decryption is `Dec(c,d,n) := cd mod n = Enc(c,d,n)` the exact same operation, where `d` is the private exponent.

If you have two different keys, then your operation would look like this:

```
c1 := Enc(m,e1,n1)
c2 := Dec(c1,d2,n2)
send c2
```

Now, if `n2 < n1`, then it can lead to a `c1 > n2` and thus not decryptable. This doesn't happen in all cases and depends on how far apart `n1` and `n2` are.

If `n2 > n1`, then the "sending" would "work", but at the receiving end, you would have reversed the order of the moduli and thus run again into a possibility of creating a recovered message that is larger than the modulus. It would look like this:

```
r1 := Enc(c2,e2,n2)
r2 := Dec(r1,d1,n1)
return r2
```

Needless to say, you shouldn't design your protocol that is dependent on chance.

---

#### How the protocol *should* look like

The protocol that you're after is called *encrypt-then-sign*. The following question and answers provide a good cache of knowledge and links on that matter: [Should we sign-then-encrypt, or encrypt-then-sign?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5458/13022)

Regardless of what you decide upon, you need to use the padded version of encryption and signature generation. In pycrypto, you should use [`Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` for encryption](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html) and [`Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_PSS` for the digital signature](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_PSS-module.html). Remember that the data that is signed, must be available for verification at the receiver side. This means that it is not possible to "encrypt with the private key", because a receiver has no way to check the data that they encrypt from that against anything.

Sender:

```
c := Enc-OAEP(m,e1,n1)
s := Sign-PSS(hash(c),d2,n2)
send c, s
```

Receiver:

```
ch := Verify-PSS(s,e2,n2)
if ch == hash(c):
    mr := Dec-OAEP(c,d1,n1)
    return mr
else:
    throw Error
```

---

> Why does the size() method return 2047 for a 2048-bit key?

That looks like a bug and shouldn't happen as seen in [this code](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/v2.6/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py#L46). Although, it's a rather minor bug.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer containing several side-aspects valuable to me!  Two questions:  ① I cannot import the `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` you mention and don't find it using `apt-file search`.  Any advice on which package I need for this?  ② You mention that c₁ > n₂ will lead to the problem, but I don't see the relation to the 2048 bit key.  It is clear that the secret/public exponent will be part of these bits, but is the n₂ also stored within these bits?

Comment: ① `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` was first included in version 2.5 of pycrypto. ② The size of the key is actually the size of the modulus. public and private exponent are not taken into account when we talk about the key size of RSA ([recent discussion](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34382/13022) about the storage size of a private key for maximum confusion). Let's say you generate two moduli n₁ and n₂, both with 2048 bits (it just means that MSB that is set is at position 2047 zero-indexed). Even when both moduli have the same bit size, they are not equal.

Comment: I know that's a completely different question, but what would one be supposed to use on a Ubuntu 12.04 which only provides the version 2.4.1 of Crypto?  My goal is to programmatically encrypt/decrypt short messages using existing RSA keys (as typically present in the ~/.ssh/ folder).  Integrity and privacy are relevant.  I'd also like to be able to send the message to several receivers, so making somehow use of more than one receivers' public keys for encrypting would be nice.

Comment: a) It seems that 2.4.1 only provides textbook RSA (I checked whether it contains the padding code somewhere else). You could take the padding code out of the newer version or you could install the newest stable pycrypto version through pip (make sure to have buildutils in order to compile tomcrypt). b) You generally would utilize [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) and devise a message format where the data is encrypted symmetrically, but has multiple asymmetrically encrypted headers (as shown in my answer) for each recipient.